# Efficient looping in grouped Dataframe to access values of current and previous index (and calculate difference)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a large data frame which looks like below. The data is sorted by id followed by OnTime

```
    id  OnTime              OffTime
0   1   2017-08-01 09:38:17 2017-08-01 09:49:31
1   1   2017-08-01 09:53:15 2017-08-01 09:54:50
2   1   2017-08-01 09:57:29 2017-08-01 10:10:42
3   2   2017-08-01 09:02:00 2017-08-01 09:27:15
4   2   2017-08-01 09:29:15 2017-08-01 09:43:41
```

I need to calculate the difference in time between current OnTime and previous OffTime, if the ids are the same. (this difference is called timeSince)

Looking for an efficient way to do it in Python. The dataframe has around 400k rows. I have thought of grouping by ids by i'm not entirely sure how I can iterate and calculate the time difference.

The output should look like below:

```
timeSince
-1 #since this is the 1st row of ID 1 no previous OffTime exists
3.7333333333333334
2.65
-1 #since this is the 1st row of ID 2 no previous OffTime exists
2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tempting to use `GroupBy` + `lambda`, but not necessary:

```
df['timeSince'] = (df['OnTime'] - df.groupby('id')['OffTime'].shift())
df['timeSince'] = (df['timeSince'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).fillna(-1)

print(df)

              OffTime              OnTime  id  timeSince
0 2017-08-01 09:49:31 2017-08-01 09:38:17   1  -1.000000
1 2017-08-01 09:54:50 2017-08-01 09:53:15   1   3.733333
2 2017-08-01 10:10:42 2017-08-01 09:57:29   1   2.650000
3 2017-08-01 09:27:15 2017-08-01 09:02:00   2  -1.000000
4 2017-08-01 09:43:41 2017-08-01 09:29:15   2   2.000000
```

Comment: Your solution works for the scenario I mentioned. It is also 4 x faster than my solution. I like your solution than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) `OffTime` by `1`. Since the output is [`TimeDelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) we need to convert this using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) then taking total `seconds` and then dividing by `60` `(1minute = 60seconds)`. Finally use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill `NaN` values with `-1` then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). The result:

```
import pandas as pd

df['OnTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OnTime'])
df['OffTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OffTime'])

df['timeSince']=df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['OnTime']-x['OffTime'].shift(1)).\
                                 apply(lambda x: x.seconds/60).fillna(-1).\
                                 reset_index(drop=True)
df

   id                OnTime             OffTime timeSince
0   1   2017-08-01 09:38:17 2017-08-01 09:49:31 -1.000000
1   1   2017-08-01 09:53:15 2017-08-01 09:54:50  3.733333
2   1   2017-08-01 09:57:29 2017-08-01 10:10:42  2.650000
3   2   2017-08-01 09:02:00 2017-08-01 09:27:15 -1.000000
4   2   2017-08-01 09:29:15 2017-08-01 09:43:41  2.000000
```

Comment: `apply` + `lambda` doesn't take advantage of vectorised computations. You should aim to avoid a manual loop, this isn't much different.

Comment: @jpp I did it because I imagined what if there is single id value like `id=3` only once then shifting directly and taking difference does not make sense right?

Comment: You can use `GroupBy` + `shift` without `apply`, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandeep. This solution works, but jpp's solution works faster given the size of the dataframe. :) Cheers!